# Requiring a Torch command line script without parsing Command line arguments

Tags: lua, torch

I have two Torch scripts. One is some code for training a model, and the other is for testing it.

The training script accepts command line arguments

```
cmd = torch.CmdLine()
cmd:option('--foo', 'bar', 'example option')
opt = cmd:parse(arg or {})
```

The testing script also accepts command line arguments. It requires the training script because it needs some functions and constants the training script defines

```
require 'training'
cmd = torch.CmdLine()
cmd:option('--bar', 'foo', 'other option')
opt = cmd:parse(arg or {})
```

When I run my testing script, it runs the `cmd:parse` call from training, and it fails because `bar` isn't a valid option to pass in. Is there a convention for how to make the cmd:parse call not happen unless it's run from the command line?

Comment: Start your training script with `if not debug.getinfo(3) then print'It is safe to invoke cmd:parse() now' end` [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9074598/1847592)

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment, `debug.getinfo(3)` gives different behavior when called from an include.

When called from the command line, `debug.getinfo(3).name` is `nil`. When called from `require` on that file, `debug.getinfo(3).name` is `pcall`. So I wrapped all the command line function into an if block that checks `debug.getinfo(3)` first. (It's analogous to `__name__ = '__main__'` from Python.)

This is with the Torch interpreter, I don't know if this works with other Lua interpreters.