# Lua : Detect if module has been 'required' or run as a script

Tags: python, lua

Does Lua have a construct that does the same thing as Python's

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  # running as a script
```

Equivalently, I'm asking if any items in the global `_ENV` are reliably different when a module is 'required' vs run as a standalone script.

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521085/main-function-in-lua

Comment: @fasouto Thanks, yes that's the question I was trying to ask.