# Detect Whether Script Was Imported or Executed in Lua

Tags: lua

In python, there is a common construction of the form `if __name__ == "__main__":` to detect whether the file was imported or executed directly. Usually, the only action taken in this conditional is to execute some "sensible, top level" function. This allows the same file to be used as a basic script and as a library module (and also as something an interactive user can import and use).

I was wondering if there is a clean and reliable way to do this in lua. I thought I could use the _REQUIREDNAME global variable, but it turns out that this was changed in Lua 5.1. Currently, the lua `require` passes arguments (in the variadic `...`), so in principle, these can be examined. However, this is either not reliable, not clean, or probably both, because obviously when a script is executed arguments can be passed. So to do this safely, you would have to examine the arguments.

FWIW, `require` passes the module name as argument 1 (the string you called `require` on), and the path to the file it eventually found as argument 2. So there is a obviously some examination that can be done to try to detect this, which if not nearly as nice as `if __name__ == "__main__":` and can always be bypassed by a user by passing two suitably constructed arguments to the script. Not exactly a security threat, but I would hope there is a better solution.

I also experimented with another method, which I found very ugly but promising. This was to use `debug.traceack()`. If the script is executed directly, the traceback is very predictable, in fact, it only has 3 lines. I thought this might be it, although, like I said, an ugly hack for sure.

Do any more frequent lua users have advice? In effect, if I am writing module X, I want to either `return X.main_func()` in script mode or `return X` in import mode.

**EDIT:**
I took out an item which was actually incorrect (and makes my traceback solution workable). Additionally, the link provided in the comment by Egor Skriptunoff did provide another trick from the debug library which is even cleaner than using the traceback. Other than that, it seems that everyone ran into the same issues as me and the lua team has been disinterested in providing an official means to support this.

Comment: Look at [this thread](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2021-02/msg00042.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the links provided by Egor, the current cleanest and safest way to do this seems to be as outlined here:

[How to determine whether my code is running in a lua module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49375638/how-to-determine-whether-my-code-is-running-in-a-lua-module)

which I repeat for ease of reference:

```
if pcall(debug.getlocal, 4, 1) then
  print("in package")
else
  print("in main script")
end
```

There is a whole thread about it here:

http://lua.2524044.n2.nabble.com/Modules-with-standalone-main-program-td7681497.html

Like I said, it seems this is a popular feature which is going to remain unsupported for the time being, but the debug.getlocal method seems to be what common lua developers have settled on for now.

Answer (score 0):

A `require()` returning in `package.loaded`.
So simply check package.loaded for what you want.

Also as a good start for more experience in that methodic i suggest to write package.preload functions for require() stuff without manipulating the path.
A simple example for showing this...

```
# /usr/local/bin/lua -i
Lua 5.4.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2021 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> package.preload.mymod=function() return {dump=function(...)
>> local args={...}
>> local test,dump=pcall(assert,args[1])
>> if test then
>> for key,value in pairs(dump) do
>> io.write(string.format("%s=%s\n",key,value)):flush()
>> end
>> return true
>> else
>> return test,dump
>> end
>> end} end
> mymod=require('mymod')
> mymod.dump(package.loaded)
string=table: 0x56693590
mymod=table: 0x566aa890
utf8=table: 0x56694d80
package=table: 0x56691ed0
math=table: 0x56693cb0
table=table: 0x566920d0
_G=table: 0x56690730
debug=table: 0x566950e0
coroutine=table: 0x56692310
os=table: 0x56692e60
io=table: 0x566921b0
true
```

Comment: Thanks, if I remember I did look into this but I think that package.loaded is nil until after the script runs, so the script itself does not know whether is executing directly or via require. I would not want to write my own modification as a solution because then it will fail on another platform.