# Can lua tell if a script is being called from another file?

Tags: lua

Can LUA tell if a script is being executed as a script or being called from within another lua file? I'm looking for a bit of lua code similar to python's:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   myfunction.run()
```

where I can execute `myfunction.run()` only if I'm calling executing the script as a standalone file.

Comment: `if not debug.getinfo(3) then script-is-standalone-file end`

Comment: Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18748160/6834680)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I did a search for this question here in SO, but didn't see the previous question. Thanks for the response and for the link.

Comment: Yes, it is hard to find similar question without knowing the answer :-)